# How can I force Entity Framework code-first to use SQL Server CE when SQL Server Express is installed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I would like to use EF code first with SQL Server CE 4 from an ASP.NET MVC project but instead of my database being created in the `App_Data` folder, I get a new database in the SQL Server Express instance installed on my workstation.

How can I get the DB created in the `App_Data` folder instead?

`web.config`:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NerdDinners" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|NerdDinners.sdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

`Context` class:

```
public class NerdDinners : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Dinner> Dinners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit 1**
I tried stopping SQL Server Express thinking that might force the use of SQL Server CE but it resulted in a `ProviderIncompatibleException` with an inner exception of

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"}

So it seems my setup wants to use SQL Server Express.

**Edit 2**
It was suggested that I explicitly pass the connection string name to the DbContext so I changed my context class to the following:

```
  public class NerdDinners : DbContext
    {
        public NerdDinners() : base("NerdDinners") { }

        public DbSet<Dinner> Dinners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }
    }
```

In the DinnersController, this is how the context is instantiated:

```
public class DinnersController : Controller
    {
        private NerdDinners db = new NerdDinners();

        //
        // GET: /Dinners/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Dinners.ToList());
        }
```

After making these changes, the DB is still being created in SQL Server Express so it appears that my connection string is being ignored.

Comment: you have it configured as above and don't get the sdf file appearing in bin/debug?

Comment: @Adam Tuliper - That is correct. I get a new DB in my local instance of SQL Server Express.

Comment: no other connect strings at all? also is sqlce v 4 installed?

Comment: @Adam Tuliper - Correct, no other connection strings. I have "System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll", "System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll" and "amd64" and "x86" subirectories in my bin folder.

Comment: try Install-Package EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact to ensure

Comment: @AdamTuliper - The result of issuing the Nuget command "Install-Package EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact" is "Unable to find package 'EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact'."

Comment: ah the package is gone now. ensure latest from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876   I have basically the same setup and it works so first thought it CE is failing. Grab my code from here and see if the test project works, you may have to uncomment out a connect string for the .sdf version I dont recall which state I left it in.  http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/02/south-florida-code-camp-entity.html

Comment: How are you creating the DbContext? Have you tried new DbContext("name=NerdDinners") to make sure it actually uses the connection string from the config file? Otherwise how DbContext should know you want to use this connection string? Note that you can have many connection strings in your config file.

Comment: you dont have to initialize it with the connect string HOWEVER - you do have to stick to a naming convention. It must match the name of your context class. If the context class is in another project, then you need to use the full namespace of it. If this is all in the same project, you do not have to specify the connect string name and it will default.

Comment: @Pawel - I updated my question with the results of your suggestion.

Comment: There are TWO web.config files in ASP.NET MVC. The connection string needs to go in the one off the root of the site and not the one in the views directory (where I had mine). Once I put the connection string in the web.config in the root of the project my SQL Server CE database was created using code first and working fine! - Someone can put this solution into an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are TWO web.config files in ASP.NET MVC. The connection string needs to go in the one off the root of the site and not the one in the views directory (where I had mine). Once I put the connection string in the web.config in the root of the project my SQL Server CE database was created using code first and working fine!

Comment: didnt even think you would've added that there  as its pretty much there to configure whats allowed for your views only. that would explain why it wouldnt find it!!   : )

Answer (score 0):

Download EFProfiler's trial, see if you can see the name of the connect string.

Ensure the rules above are followed. If you want to send me a sample project, I'll check it out for you but mine works ok not specifying a connect string and using sql ce. Download my demo project at the link above - did it work? If not I'd question the CE binaries.

Is your context class in the same project? Is your connect string named the same as your context class (it should be)

In other words, you your web.config you have NerdDinners, it your context class actually named NerdDinners, if not it needs to be or change the id in the connect string.